# Discord.py bot not formatting text in footer in embed

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to bold my text in footer in embed like **this**, but it's not working there, and it's working on the rest of the embed.
My code:

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
  user = ctx.author
  true_member_count = len([m for m in ctx.guild.members if not m.bot])
  guild = bot.get_guild(959460466223120405)
  embed = discord.Embed(name=f"\u200b", description=f"Welcome **{user}**!", color=discord.Color.from_rgb(129, 199, 250))
  embed.set_footer(text=f"You are **{true_member_count}** user on this server!!", icon_url=user.avatar_url)
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

And this is the result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/moBwA.jpg.
Does anyone know why is this happening?
Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The embed footer text doesn't support Markdown, whereas `description` does.

I couldn't find any mention of this in the official Discord or Discord.py docs, but it is mentioned in this [Discord Webhooks Guide](https://birdie0.github.io/discord-webhooks-guide/structure/embed/footer.html) and on an [old Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Discord_Bots/comments/b01hua/need_help_with_footer_in_discordjs/).